# Catch all events performed by user in a winforms Application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio, clr

I need to create a logfile of all the events that user performs (button clicked, selection changed, texbox text changed etc.) what do you recommend me as the best approach to achieve this?

I was thinking of some kind of supervisor, but I have no idea how to implement this. Can IMessage be used for this kind of task?

Comment: What sort of details shall be in the log? Only the event and the time or also data like SelectedIndex or SelectedItem or SelectedText or CheckBox.CheckState etc..?

Comment: Prefereably logging what event was raised and key properties of a control that raised it like item.Text, item.SelectedText and so on.

Comment: Sure, IMessageFilter lets you peek at all user input events.  Mouse and keyboard, not what those events actually do (like selections).  Lots and lots of sample code available that shows how to use Application.AddMessageFilter(), you don't need one more.